# Set a custom FolderBrowserDialog.RootFolder

Tags: vb.net

My application wants to offer the client a range of options sets. Each set contains 60 options, variations on a theme. The sets are stored in a folder. Set1 set2 etc. I want to use a the folder browser to select a set but I don't want the user to see the whole drive. I want to set the root folder to the set parent. I have tried using RootFolder but I see that won't work. I also tried using the fileopenDialog but I can't select a folder. Is there a third option?

Comment: Use `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles()`and a `ListBox` ?

Comment: You could hide all the implementation details from the user by letting them name the sets.  Then when they pick a name - your code loads the related set for them.  No need for **them** to remember what "set01" means or where they stored it.

Answer (score 0):

RootFolder sort of works when combined with SelectedPath

```
    Using fbd As New FolderBrowserDialog
        fbd.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer
        fbd.SelectedPath = "H:\temp\scans"
        If fbd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            MsgBox(fbd.SelectedPath)
        End If
    End Using
```

This at least displays the desired folder - all the other paths are still available if the user scrolls up.

---

This is the closest I've found searching the Internet using the standard OpenFileDialog:

```
    Using obj As New OpenFileDialog
        obj.Filter = "foldersOnly|*.none"
        obj.CheckFileExists = False
        obj.CheckPathExists = False
        obj.InitialDirectory = "C:\temp"
        obj.CustomPlaces.Add("H:\OIS") ' add custom location
        obj.CustomPlaces.Add("H:\Permits") ' add custom location
        obj.Title = "Select folder - click Open to return opened folder name"
        obj.FileName = "OpenFldrPath"
        If obj.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            MsgBox(IO.Directory.GetParent(obj.FileName).FullName)
        End If
    End Using
```

Edit CustomPlaces.Add() for your environment - these folders appear in the top right nav panel.

`obj.FileName = "OpenFldrPath"' is problematic - restrictions on what can be used e.g. a phrase fails.

Takes two clicks on Open to return the file path.